# Calling a stored proc in a foreach loop throwing 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition' exception

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm writing some code that attempts to loop through a list of recipient ids, but with the same message id and owner id for each recipient id and at each iteration, execute a `stored procedure`. In testing, I keep getting the 
aforementioned error.

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition

Now I've tested the data extensively at the database level, the stored procedure is working just fine, so I'm reasonably sure its here in the `C#` code. I've made sure the parameter names are exact, and that they are the same corresponding types, etc. I've tested with the same sample data. My object model looks like this:

```
public class ShareModel
{
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public List<int> RecipientIds { get; set; }
}
```

And my method:

```
public void ShareMessage(ShareBindingModel shares)
    {
        try
        {
            var msgId = shares.MessageId;
            var ownerId = shares.OwnerId;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                foreach (var i in shares.RecipientIds)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ForwardMessage", conn))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new_recipient_id", i);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@src_msgid", msgId);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fwdperson_id", ownerId);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Stored procedure (I did not write this):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ForwardMessage]
 @new_recipient_id int,
 @src_msgid varchar(30),
 @fwdperson_id int
AS
BEGIN
declare @new_msgid varchar(30)
declare @tenant_id int
declare @sender_id int
declare @action_dt datetime

select @tenant_id=tenant_id, 
       @sender_id=sender_id,
       @action_dt=getdate() 
  from message 
 where msg_id=@src_msgid

exec dbo.GenerateString 1,1,1,null,30,@new_msgid OUT
insert into message
SELECT  @new_msgid
  ,[tenant_id]
  ,[sender_id]
  ,@new_recipient_id
  ,(select email_addr from person_email where person_id=@new_recipient_id )
  ,[description]
  ,[date_recorded]
  ,[filename]
  ,[size_bytes]
  ,[size_time]
  ,[filepath]
  ,[Flag]
  ,[title]
  ,[date_activity]

  FROM [message]
  where tenant_id=@tenant_id
and msg_id=@src_msgid

END
```

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please show SP definition as well?

Comment: The message is pretty clear: your sproc specifies *x* number of columns, and you're calling it with *y* number of columns.

Comment: Without the stored procedure definition it's impossible to help you with anything other than "you're calling it wrong".

Comment: Consider changing this "throw new Exception(ex.Message);" to "throw;" When you re-wrap the exception the way you are doing it, you lose useful stack trace details.

Comment: My gut instinct is to say that it's because you're not clearing parameters before initially setting them, since this is being executed in a loop...

Comment: I'm guessing that error would be coming from the INSERT statement in the stored procedure. What's the definition of the `message` table?

Comment: Matt Gibson - that's exactly what was wrong, had an extra column in the table that wasn't in the stored procedure. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition` points to a problem when inserting to a table. As your only `INSERT` is the `insert into message...` from your stored procedure, I'd wager that that's the problem, and that there is a mismatch between the column list for that `INSERT` and the columns of the table itself.

(I'm not sure why this would be the case if "the stored procedure is working just fine", as you say, but it's the only possible answer given the evidence.)

Comment: There was a time lapse in between when I tested it at the SQL Server level and when tested the C# code. Someone had added a column in that time.

Answer (score 2):

Usually either you're not calling the stored procedure you think you are (try to specify the schema too) or the parameters required by the stored procedure are different from the ones you're supplying.